# SQL finding max value from union table

Tags: postgresql

I was working on the stratescratch question and was getting down on the facebook interview question on Highest Energy Consumption. it is basically giving me 3 table of energy consumption on different dates from 3 different data centre and I have to find total sum of energy consumption across all data centres on the same date, then find the maximum energy consumption among all

https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/10064-highest-energy-consumption?python=

So my initial code is as the following:

```
with total as 
(select a.date, sum(a.consumption) as sumofall
from(
    select date, consumption
    from fb_eu_energy
    union all
    select date, consumption
    from fb_asia_energy
    union all
    select date, consumption
    from fb_na_energy) as a
    group by a.date)
select date, max(sumofall)
from total;
```

Which does not work unless I do this:

```
with total as 
(select a.date, sum(a.consumption) as sumofall
from(
    select date, consumption
    from fb_eu_energy
    union all
    select date, consumption
    from fb_asia_energy
    union all
    select date, consumption
    from fb_na_energy) as a
    group by a.date)
select date, sumofall
from total
where sumofall = (select max(sumofall) from total);
```

I can't really understand why i have to declare sumofall again?

Comment: Where do you declare sumofall again? The first one simply selects the max of sumofall, no? What you need is to find those having sumofall equal to that max(sumofall).

Comment: yes, that is what i thought too. So i initially use max(sumofall) based on the "total" table i formed before. But i have error and i dig into the suggested answer that require me to declare again

Comment: There is not 'declare again'. Where is it? It is the right way of writing it. There are other ways too but that one is fine.